# Find the total number of surjections (onto functions) from the set $[5] = \{ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 \}$ to the set $[2] = \{ 1 , 2 \}$ .

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Here is what I got.

Every surjective function $f$ sends $4$ elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to the same element of $\{1,2\}$. So ${5\choose 4}=5$ 
for a given pair there $\{i,j\}$ subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
So $2!$ surjective functions such that $f(i) = f(j)$. So $5 \cdot 2!$?
And here is where I'm stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The function $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=1$ and $f(4)=f(5)=2$ sends $4$ elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to **which** element of $\{1,2\}?$ By the way $\binom54\ne10.$

Comment: If we don't care about surjections, how many **functions** are there from the set $[5]$ to the set $[2]$? And now, how many of those are **not** surjections?

Comment: Consider all possible functions from [5] to [2], there are three possibility: all maps to 1, all maps to 2, and surjective. Can you proceed?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

One way to see this is to partition [5] into two non empty subsets(corresponding to the preimages of 1 and 2 respectively). This can be done in $ 2^5-2$ ways . So number of surjections=30

Comment: OK so what if i had set |4| = {1,2,3,4} to set |3| = {1,2,3} would i use the same train of thought? so $3^4-3$?

Comment: Not really then ur answer will also rule out functions that completely leave out only 1 element. In other words here we were lucky that non surjective functions have to be constant. In general we don't have the luxury

Answer (score 3):

A function is determined by which element in the codomain is assigned to each element in the domain.  Since there are two choices in the codomain for each of the five elements in the domain, there are $2^5$ functions $f: [5] \to [2]$.  Of these, only the two constant functions are not surjective, so $2^5 - 2 = 30$ functions are surjective.

In the comments below Soumik Ghosh's answer, you asked how many surjective functions there are from the set $[4] = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ to the set $[3] = \{1, 2, 3\}$.  We use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Since there are three choices in the codomain for each of the four elements in the domain, there are $3^4$ functions $f: [4] \to [3]$.  From these, we must exclude those that are not surjective.

There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to exclude one of the three elements in the codomain from the range and two ways to assign one of the remaining elements in the codomain to each element in the range.  Thus, there are 
$$\binom{3}{1}2^4$$
functions $f: [4] \to [3]$ that exclude one element from the range.

However, if we subtract this amount from the total, we have subtracted those functions with only one element in the range twice, once for each way we could have excluded one of the other two elements from the range.  Since we only want to subtract them once, we must add the number of constant functions.  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to exclude two of the three elements in the codomain from the range and one way to assign each element in the domain to the remaining element in the codomain.  Hence, the number of surjective functions $f: [4] \to [3]$ is 
$$3^4 - \binom{3}{1}2^4 + \binom{3}{2}1^4$$

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

The above link represents Sterling's number of 2nd kind known as $S(n,k)$.

Its recurrence relation is defined as $S(n+1, k) = k* S(n, k) + S(n, k-1)$

---

Number of Onto(Surjective Functions) = $k!.S(n,k)$ = $2!.S(5,2) =30$

---

Sterling's triangle :-

$1$

$1\ 1$

$1\ 3\ 1$

$1\ 7\ 6\ 1$

$1\ 15\ 25\ 10\ 1$ and so on